# Dungeon Crawler Movement not moving in the correct direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working in Unity and I have an issue with my playercontroller.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
 {
 
     Vector3 pos;                                // For movement
    public float speed = 2.0f;                         // Speed of movement

IEnumerator RotateMe(Vector3 byAngles, float inTime)

      
     {    var fromAngle = transform.rotation;
         var toAngle = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles);
         for(var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime/inTime) {
             transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(fromAngle, toAngle, t);
             yield return null;
         }
     }  

 
     void Start()
     {
         pos = transform.position;          // Take the initial position
     }
 
     void Update()
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && transform.position == pos)
         {        // Left
             pos+= Vector3.left;
         }
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && transform.position == pos)
         {        // Right
             pos+= Vector3.right;
         }
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && transform.position == pos)
         {        // Up
             pos += Vector3.forward;
         }
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && transform.position == pos)
         {        // Down
             pos += Vector3.back;
             
         }
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q) && transform.position == pos)
        {
            StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.up * -90, 0.8f));
        }
            //Rotate Left
         transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, pos, Time.deltaTime * speed);    // Move there
     }
 
 }
```

When I hit Q, I turn 90 degrees but when I hit W, I continue forward relative to the map. How do I move forward in the direction that I am facing? Also, Should I be attaching this script to the game camera or a player body?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to maintain both position and direction.  When you advance, you can't just go `Vector3.forward`, you have to "advance in the direction I am facing.  One way (there are others) is to keep an array of four directions, starting with left, right, forward back.  Then, when you rotate, you just rotate the elements of that array.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

  Vector3 pos;                                // For movement
  public float speed = 2.0f;                         // Speed of movement
  public Transform relativeTransform;

  IEnumerator RotateMe(Vector3 byAngles, float inTime)


  {
    var fromAngle = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime)
    {
      transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(fromAngle, toAngle, t);
      yield return null;
    }
  }


  void Start()
  {
    pos = transform.position;          // Take the initial position
  }

  void Update()
  {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Left
      pos += -relativeTransform.right;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Right
      pos += relativeTransform.right;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Up
      pos += relativeTransform.forward;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Down
      pos += -relativeTransform.forward;

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q) && transform.position == pos)
    {
      StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.up * -90, 0.8f));
    } //Rotate Left

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && transform.position == pos)
    {
      StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.up * 90, 0.8f));
    } //Rotate Right
    
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, pos, Time.deltaTime * speed);    // Move there
  }

}
```

relativeTransform was needed instead of Vector3.forwards. Thanks for letting me rubber duck!